# What does "$DATA (nonresident)" mean?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ntfs

There was a blackout in my home and my computer's hard drives' filesystems were corrupted.

I checked the system files and the hardware, and found no problem. But I did the stupid thing of running `chkdsk /f X:` first and it had found and deleted corrupt attribute records from 16659 files.

Now I think all these files may be corrupted.

I took ownership of the "System Volume Information" folders and found the complete logs inside the Chkdsk folder there.

And I use nfi.exe to get the affected files from the sector numbers. I am trying to write a program using `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec` to do that.

But first I want to understand the output of `nfi.exe`.

```
PS C:\Users\Xeni> D:\downloads\nfi\nfi.exe D: 0x9379dc5
NTFS File Sector Information Utility.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1999. All rights reserved.


***Logical sector 154639813 (0x9379dc5) on drive D is in file number 551312.
\Games\Saints Row 4\packfiles\pc\cache\dlc3.vpp_pc
    $STANDARD_INFORMATION (resident)
    $FILE_NAME (resident)
    $FILE_NAME (resident)
    $DATA (nonresident)
        logical sectors 154625064-154690687 (0x9376428-0x938647f)
```

What does the output mean? What is `$DATA (nonresident)`? Does it mean the metadata and filename are kept but the data of the file is gone, the file is a "ghost file"?

I tried to Google search `"$DATA (nonresident)"` and found absolutely nothing about its meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in Wikipedia
[NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) :

> For each file (or directory) described in the MFT record, there is a
> linear repository of stream descriptors (also named attributes),
> packed together in one or more MFT records (containing the so-called
> attributes list), with extra padding to fill the fixed 1 KB size of
> every MFT record, and that fully describes the effective streams
> associated with that file.
>
> Each attribute has an attribute type (a fixed-size integer mapping to
> an attribute definition in file $AttrDef), an optional attribute name
> (for example, used as the name for an alternate data stream), and a
> value, represented in a sequence of bytes. For NTFS, the standard data
> of files, the alternate data streams, or the index data for
> directories are stored as attributes.
>
> According to $AttrDef, some attributes can be either resident or
> non-resident. The **$DATA attribute, which contains file data**, is
> such an example. When the attribute is **resident (which is
> represented by a flag), its value is stored directly in the MFT
> record**. Otherwise, clusters are allocated for the data, and the
> **cluster location information is stored as data runs in the attribute**.

`nfi.exe` lists the NTFS attributes. Resident means from the MFT,
nonresident means from the attibute itself.

Answer (score 1):

**Sample output from NFI for a file**

> PS C:\Users\Xeni> D:\downloads\nfi\nfi.exe D: 0x9379dc5
> NTFS File Sector Information Utility.
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1999. All rights reserved.
> ***Logical sector 154639813 (0x9379dc5) on drive D is in file number 551312.
> \Games\Saints Row 4\packfiles\pc\cache\dlc3.vpp_pc
> $STANDARD_INFORMATION (resident)
> $FILE_NAME (resident)
> $FILE_NAME (resident)
> $DATA (nonresident)
> logical sectors 154625064-154690687 (0x9376428-0x938647f)

Your command is asking information about the sector 0x9379dc5 of the volume D:.

**Representing a file as an entry in the MFT**
The file number 551312 is referring to an entry in a table called MFT. Technically in NTFS every file is represented by an entry number in the MFT table.
The MFT is realized as a file with fixed-length entries of a length of typically 1024 bytes.
Every file in NTFS is typically represented by one entry. The sector you are looking for belongs to entry number 551312 in the MFT.

**Attributes of an MFT entry**
The entry assigns so-called standard attributes to this number, such as a name, dates (coded in $STANDARD_INFORMATION).
The keyword "resident/nonresident" just tells you if this attribute can be found within that MFT entry or somewhere else - outside of the MFT.

Some attributes are always resident like $STANDARD_INFORMATION.
The content of a file, the data, can be located within the associated MFT entry when it is small enough to fit into the entry itself. In this case the data would be described as "resident". Your file data is too big to fit into the entry so it has to be stored somewhere else and is thus labeled as "nonresident".
Internally NTFS uses cluster numbers to point to data. Standard clusters in my environment contain 8 512-byte-sectors per cluster.
Luckily, NFI already decoded those cluster numbers into logical sectors.

I guess the line `logical sectors 154625064-154690687 (0x9376428-0x938647f)`
refers to first and the last data sector of your file relative to the start of the volume.
To decode that sector number into an (absolute) disk sector you would need to add the sector number of the start of your volume to both figures given above.

To better understand the output of NFI, partition a disk, for instance a small pen drive with two partitions, each one disposing about half the free space. Then write a small and a large text file into the second partition and run NFI to see what this gives.